# Upon import, isosphere is missing

Tags: unity, blender

To build my tank for a Unity game, I am using Blender. Currently, I am making a turret consisting of an isosphere with half of the faces removed (I needed the bottom to be "flat") with some minor visual edits, two cylinders (one is the hatch, the other the antenna), and a cube to act as a hinge:

[image]

The inside is hollow. When I imported it to Unity (drag and drop from File Explorer straight to Unity Assets folder), the entire isosphere was missing as you can see from the preview:

[image]

I have tried to correct the normals with CTRL-N as mentioned in other Blender forum pages but it still doesn't work. How exactly do I make my isosphere appear in Unity?

**NOTE:** This works if imported as a `.fbx` file but I would much prefer the file to be a `.blend` file instead (which is default).

Comment: How about reversing the normals and check again? Then you will know for sure if it's normals or something else.

Comment: @Charanor I did and it still didn't work